Application Passwords only for admin user?
I was wondering if it is possible to only allow the Application Password feature for admin users. I have found this page about it: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/
But their code does not work for me. The function below just makes the Application Password feature not working, for all users. Am I missing something? Thanks!
function my_prefix_customize_app_password_availability(
    $available,
    $user
) {
    if ( ! user_can( $user, 'manage_options' ) ) {
        $available = false;
    }
 
    return $available;
}
 
add_filter(
    'wp_is_application_passwords_available_for_user',
    'my_prefix_customize_app_password_availability',
    10,
    2
);


When you say it doesn't work for you, do you mean that non-admin users can authenticate with application passwords? or admin users can't? Or something else?

The blog is four years old so it's possible something's changed. Can you add trace to the function e.g. error_log() calls, to see what's happening - whether this is being called, whether $user is initialised correctly, whether the user_can result is what you expect, etc.

Hi, thanks for your reply. It doesn't work means that the application passwords don't work anymore. So the thirdparty app can't connect anymore.

edit your question to add the debug you made. if your filter is not called, look at filter wp_is_application_passwords_available.

Apparently the above code seems to work now. Had to do with a cache? Or maybe the code does not work when you try to connect with an earlier Application Password (a password that was generated before the code was added).
EDIT: For anyone also using the Woocommerce app on the mobile.
The above function will not work, once authenticated. This means it is not possible to obtain the stats with the function above. You can use this function to check the user by ID. This works, if you only want to allow the admin to use Application Passwords and your user ID is 1:
function my_prefix_customize_app_password_availability(
    $available,
    $user
) {
    if ( $user !== 1 ) {
        $available = false;
    }
 
    return $available;
}
 
add_filter(
    'wp_is_application_passwords_available_for_user',
    'my_prefix_customize_app_password_availability',
    10,
    2
);

